# HTTP POST Method - Invoking of Class

Tags: .net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

### The Controller:

```
Public Class TheColorNameRequestClass
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    ' This method will handle GET'
    Function TheGET() As ActionResult
        Return View()
    End Function

    ' This method will handle POST'
    <HttpPost()> _
    Function TheRequest(ByVal ColorName As String) As ActionResult
        ' Do something'
        Response.Write("The color name submitted is:, " & Request.Form("ColorName"))
        Return View()
    End Function

End Class
```

### The HTML, (The View):

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="UserName" id="UserName" />
    <input type="submit" name="UserName_submit" value="Print It Out!" />
</form>
```

### The Question:

After pressing the `Submit Button`, how is the `Class` in the `Controller` - including the function called `TheRequest` - *invoked*?

In this case, I am directing the question to the process, of having the `Controller` scanned for the *Class* and the *Functions*, - ***after*** - the *submit button* is pressed, so that the `request` can be done correctly to the `HTTP POST method`.

---

The given is the `current HTTP request`, after pressing the `Submit Button`. Where the `Request.Form` method does do the request specifically for the "ColorName", submitted through the form.

By my PHP experience, I am thinking of having the ***"action attribute of the form"*** contain the name of the controller, so it can start scanning each line, after the *submit button* is pressed. This is said as an example.

*The question has been modified.*

---

***Invoked*** = to put into effect or operation *(Source: The Merriam-Webster Dictionary)*

Comment: Maybe you want this ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd695917.aspx . And btw asp.net is NOT php they're very different, even if C# and php share C syntax

Comment: It is really something, where the `Controller` needs to be scanned for the Class and the Functions, after the submit button is pressed.

Comment: Please take a look here: [How a Method Becomes An Action](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/08/29/how-a-method-becomes-an-action.aspx) it describeds the process in ver simple way. Let me know if that helps than I will post this as an answer.

Comment: I suggest you learn more about asp.net and .net itself. .Net apps are compiled and not interpreted like php is.